# Passing a JSF parameter not implementing setter method

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have a datatable with a commandlink which i want to pass an object to the bean. The action attribute on the commandlink direct to the same page ie. there's no navigation. As a result (i think/suspect),or for some other reason, the setter method in the bean isn't being implemented hence my object in the beanis null. How can i sort this out plz. Below are extracts from the datatable and the setter and my method. Thnx

```
<h:commandLink value="Delete"actionListener="#bOQMasterManager.removeBOQ}" action="boqmaster">
     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bOQMasterManager.boqmasterPK}" 
        value="#{boqs.boqmasterPK}" />
   </h:commandLink>


public void setBoqmasterPK(BoqmasterPK boqmasterPK) {
     System.out.println("In the setter!!!");
    this.boqmasterPK = boqmasterPK;

}

public void removeBOQ(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        System.out.println("In removeBOQ!!!");

        request.removeBoq(boqmasterPK);
        logger.info("Removed BOQ .");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("In the exception!!!"+e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe showing us the relevant jsf section could help us in analysis

Comment: What do you mean with "(I think) the setter method in the bean isn't being implemented"? Either it is implemented or not.

Comment: Sorry, i though i had put the jsf section, lemme edit the post. sorry

Comment: It setter isn't being implemented.

Comment: "implemented" or "called/executed". Implemented means that the code for it has been written.

Comment: sorry, the setter isn't being called

Comment: Do you have a converter for BoqmasterPK?

Comment: no, no converter for BoqmasterPK

Comment: Have you checked your logs for exceptions? Errors in handling actionlisteners won't affect the program execution, but will appear in the server log

Comment: Ok,will let u know what the problem was when i sort it out, thnx.

Answer (score 0):

First I hope

```
actionListener="#bOQMasterManager.removeBOQ}"
```

is

```
actionListener="#{bOQMasterManager.removeBOQ}"
```

And `setBoqmasterPK` is defined in `bOQMasterManager` Bean and `getBoqmasterPK` must be defined in `boqs` whatever it is.

```
public void setBoqmasterPK(BoqmasterPK boqmasterPK) {
    System.out.println("In the setter!!!");
    this.boqmasterPK = boqmasterPK;
}
```